# Entity framework 6 easiest way to denormalize column to avoid frequent joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's assume, I have two entities.

```
class Author{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    //.....
}
class Article{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int AuthorId{get;set;}
    public string Text{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to add to Article `AuthorName` property doubling existing Author.Name to simplify resulting linq queries and execution time. I'm sure that my database will be used by only one Asp.Net MVC project. What is common way to implement such a column using EF (without database triggers)?

Also here can be a bit more difficult case. Let's say I want to have `TotalWordCountInAllArticles` column in `Author` entity which calculated by Text property of Article.

Comment: what did you mean by this `denormalize column to avoid frequent joins` ? Can't you use FK on the above models or what ?

Comment: You can do it manually wherever you save your Article from

Comment: If authorname and author are serving same purpose why do you need it in first place, also totalwordcount would be better implemented as a methon in repository as it is not attribute of the entity but composed column based on other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `AuthorName` property to `Article` and just manually keep the integrity by making sure that any code that creates `Articles` or updates the `Author.Name` also updates all of the `Articles`.  Same thing with `TotalWordCount`, and time the `Article.Text` changes, re-add up all of the counts from the other `Articles`.

There are a few patterns you could look at to make this more automatic, such as a Domain Event pattern (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/), but it definitely isn't just plug and play.  Really depends on if these are just a couple of items or if this is going to happen frequently.

If you are frequently denormalizing data for performance, you may want to look at more of an architecture where there is a normalized DB and then a separate process which generates denormalized views on the data and put into a document store.

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE:** This might not answer the EF part of your question but it does offer an alternative solution to your problem.

Not sure how far along you are into the development of your project but you may want to consider having a look at [Drapper](https://github.com/sextondjc/Drapper) which would make this trivial, fast and offer a number of other benefits.

Let's assume a small change to your Article model to include the Author model.

```
public class Article 
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    // using Author model
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

And assuming that the SQL you'd expect to execute would be something conceptually similar to:

```
select article.[Id]
    ,article.[Text]
    ,article.[AuthorId]
    ,author.Name
from [Article] article
    join [Author] author on author.AuthorId = article.AuthorId;
```

Implementing a repository to retrieve them with Drapper would be really trivial. It might look something like:

```
public class ArticleRepository : IArticleRepository
{
    // IDbCommander is a Drapper construct
    private readonly IDbCommander _commander;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ArticleRepository"/> class, 
    /// injecting an instance of the IDbCommander using your IoC framework of 
    /// choice. 
    /// </summary>
    public ArticleRepository(IDbCommander commander)
    {
        _commander = commander;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves all article instances. 
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Article> RetrieveAll()
    {
        // pass the query method a reference to a 
        // mapping function (Func<T1, T2, TResult>) 

        // although you *could* pass the predicate 
        // in right here, the code is more readable
        // when it's separated out. 
        return _commander.Query(Map.AuthorToArticle);            
    }

    private static class Map
    {
        // simple mapping function which allows you
        // to map out exactly what you want, exactly
        // how you want it. no hoop jumping!
        internal static Func<Article, Author, Article> 
            AuthorToArticle = (article, author) =>
        {
            article.Author = author;
            return article;
        };
    }
}
```

You'd wire the SQL to the repository using the configuration available to Drapper. It supports both json and xml config files or you could configure it all in code as well if you wanted to.

I've thrown a quick sample together for you over on [Github](https://github.com/sextondjc/Samples/).

*Why should you consider this?*
There's a number of benefits to going this route:

- You indicated a performance concern (execution time). Drapper is an abstraction layer built on top of Dapper - the king of high performance micro-ORM's.
- You control the mapping of your objects explicitly - no weird semantics or framework quirks (like the one you're facing).
- No auto generated SQL. You decide *exactly* what SQL will be executed.
- Your SQL is separated from your C# - if your schema changes (perhaps to improve performance) there's *no* *need* to recompile your project, change your entity mapping or alter any of your domain code or repository logic. You simply update the SQL code in your configuration.
- Along the same lines, you can design your service/repository layers to be more domain friendly without having to be concerned about data access concerns polluting your service layer (or vice versa).
- Fully testable - you can easily mock the results from the IDbCommander.
- Less coding - no need for *both* entities and dto's (unless you want them), no overriding `OnModelCreating` methods or deriving from DbContext, no special attributes on your POCO's.

And that's just the tip of the iceberg.